# How to spyOn a service to test it -- AngularJS/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, code-coverage

Have tried everything I've found on the internet to make this work with no success. Trying to test a function in my service, but according to my coverage I'm never accessing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Service').service('configService', function(
  $rootScope, $http) {
  var configObj = null;
  return {

    getConfig: function() {
      if (configObj != null) {
        console.log("returning cached config");
        return configObj;
      }
      else {
        return $http.get('conf.json').then(function(res) {
          $http.get(res.confLocation).then(function(
            locationResponse) {
            configObj = locationResponse;
            $rootScope.configObj = configObj;
            console.log($rootScope.configObj);
            return configObj;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

*getConfig* is never being accessed in the tests I've tried.

ServiceTests:

```
'use strict';
describe('Service: configService', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('Service'));

  var configService, $httpBackend, results, tstLocation, tstRes;
  var tstConfig = {
    "confLocation": "local-dev-conf.json"
  };

  var tstConfigEmpty = {};
  var tstConfigObjEmpty = {};

  var tstConfigObj = {
    "AWS": {
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:8133"
    }
  };

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function(_configService_, _$httpBackend_) {
    inject(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.USERNAME = 'TESTER';
      $rootScope.configObj = tstConfigObj;
      $rootScope.locationResponse = tstLocation;
      $rootScope.res = tstRes;
    });

    configService = _configService_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    //Problem here??
    spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        then: function() {
          return "something";
        }
      };
    });

  }));
  it('should return a promise', function() {
    expect(configService.getConfig().then).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should test backend stuff', inject(function() {

    results = configService.getConfig(tstConfig);
    $httpBackend.expectGET('conf.json').respond(tstConfig);
    $httpBackend.expectGET('local-dev-conf.json').respond(tstConfigObj);
    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));

  //Thanks Miles
  it('should check if it was called', inject(function() {
    results = configService.getConfig().then();
    expect(configService.getConfig).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
    // console.log(results);
  }));

  it('should check for a null configObj', inject(function() {
    results = configService.getConfig(tstConfigObjEmpty).then(function() {
      expect(results).toBe(null);
    });
    // console.log(results);
    // console.log(tstConfigObj);
  }));

  it('should check for a non-null configObj', inject(function() {
    results = configService.getConfig(tstConfigObj).then(function() {

      // Any string is accepted right now -- Why??
      expect(results).toEqual("returning cached config");
      expect(results).toBe("returning cached config");
      expect(results).toBe("your mom"); // SHOULDN'T BE WORKING BUT DOES
      expect(results).toEqual("Object{AWS: Object{region: 'us-east-1', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8133'}}");
      expect(results).toBe("Object{AWS: Object{region: 'us-east-1', endpoint: 'http://localhost:8133'}}");
    });
    // console.log(results);
    // console.log(tstConfigObj);
  }));

  it('should check for null file', inject(function() {
    results = configService.getConfig(tstConfigEmpty).then(function() {
      expect(results).toEqual(null);
      expect(results).toBe(null);
    });
  }));

  it('should test a valid file', inject(function() {
    results = configService.getConfig(tstConfig).then(function() {
      expect(results).not.toBe(null);
      expect(results).toEqual("Object{confLocation: 'local-dev-conf.json'}");
    })
});
```

I think I'm using spyOn wrong, or not accessing *getConfig* in my tests properly. Thoughts?

EDIT: [Here is my code coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsLxv.png)

EDIT 2: Changed test 3 thanks to a problem found by Miles, still no update on test coverage though. Something is wrong with my spyOn logic as Amy pointed out. I shouldn't be using callFake it seems?

EDIT 3: **Got it accessing the function now thanks to Miles.** Had to change my spyOn to:

```
spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.callThrough();
```

then add the test case:

```
results = configService.getConfig(tstConfig).then();   
expect(configService.getConfig).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

[Coverage now (still needs work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fMxz.png)

Comment: Have you tried and.returnValue instead of and.callFake and just return the thenable?

Comment: I have tried replacing and.callFake with and.returnValue, as well as:

"spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.returnValue(function() {
      return {
        then: function() {
          return "something";"

Crashes 6 of my 9 tests when I do that

Comment: Note that there's no need to check that a function was called in the very next line _after you called it_!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue here:

```
results = configService.getConfig(tstConfigObj).then(function() {
  expect(results).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(results).toHaveBeenCalledWith(tstConfigObj);
});
```

`getConfig` takes no parameters, and neither does `then`. Omitting these errors, `results` is assigned the string "something" from `then`. Even if the `expect` statements fire, you seem to be testing if a string has been called. Try this instead:

```
results = configService.getConfig().then();
expect(configService.getConfig).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Miles. I implemented the change, and though the test did pass, it still isn't providing any coverage of the *getConfig*...

I think there is a problem with my spyOn, as Amy mentioned above, but I'm a little unsure how to fix that.

Comment: Did you try `spyOn(configService, 'getConfig').and.callThrough();` then doing `results = configService.getConfig(tstConfig).then();` and finally `expect(configService.getConfig).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: That did it! It finally accessed the function, and I'm at 42% coverage. Time to work on the rest of the code, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Based on your posted code, I'm not sure that's a victory. Just testing that the function was called doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it doesn't help the OP with his actual issue (not understanding what spying does). I'm not downvoting, but this is not a good answer despite being accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a fake instead of the function. So the logic inside of the function does not get called.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little? I'm fairly new to Angular/Jasmine and don't quite understand spyOn yet. Thanks!

Comment: Don't spy on a function unless you need to test that it has been called (so you might spy on a function in this service in a test for something that uses it). If you need to spy on it _and_ you need the code in it to run, use `and.callThrough` as @Miles P said in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Jasmine are you using? The and.callFake syntax was added in Jasmine 2.0. Maybe the test suite just needs to point to the new version.

[Jasmine 1.3 Docs](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html)

[Jasmine 2.0 Docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

Comment: I am using Jasmine 2.4.1